# How to convert AudioStream to Base64 encoded string(Bytes?) in Python

Tags: python, base64

I am calling an API that returns an AudioStream in response. Then I need to return it to the user in the responseObject. My current code looks like below. I feel like I may be doing double the work here. First AudioStream is saved to a file, and then I am reading it and encoding it. Thanks! The audiostream is mp3 currently. I have options of ogg_vorbis and pcm also in this api I am calling.

```
if "AudioStream" in response:
    # Note: Closing the stream is important because the service throttles on the
    # number of parallel connections. Here we are using contextlib.closing to
    # ensure the close method of the stream object will be called automatically
    # at the end of the with statement's scope.
    with closing(response["AudioStream"]) as stream:
        output = "/tmp/speech.mp3"
        print('output')

        try:
            # Open a file for writing the output as a binary stream
            with open(output, "wb") as file:
                file.write(stream.read())

            with open("/tmp/speech.mp3", "rb") as mp3_file:
                encoded_string = base64.b64encode(mp3_file.read())

            print('written')
            responseObject = {}
            responseObject['statusCode'] = 200
            responseObject['headers'] = {}
            responseObject['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'audio/mpeg'
            responseObject['isBase64Encoded'] = 'true'
            response = encoded_string
            response = response.decode('utf-8')
            responseObject['body'] = response
            print('response ready')
            return responseObject
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't call `b64encode` with `stream.read()` instead of `mp3_file.read()`?